Traveling between two Schengen Countries using a Verlustanzeige?
I am a romanian citizen living legally in Germany, and have recently lost my ID, and my Passport has expired.
Next month I have a trip scheduled, and id travel from Germany to Czechia and back, the city in Czechia is around 10-15 minutes from the border.
I have a Verlustanzeige from the police station, is that enough in case we get checked at the border?
For context, I am 17.
Thank you!

A Verlustanzeige is not sufficient to fulfil the requirement that you need to carry an id or travel documents when crossing the border between Germany and Czechia. Chances are relatively low that you run into an immigration check at the border, but if you do, you must expect to be fined. I am not sure how the Czech border police will handle the matter, but you can not expect the German police to be lenient.
Are you not able to apply for a new id at a Romanian consulate? If travel is urgent, Romanian consulates should at least be able to issue emergency travel documents.

The Romanian Consulate told me there isnt anything they can do and that they wont issue me emergency documents or such, unless it is for traveling to Romania to get new documents, which I cant currently. Would an expired (less than a year) passport be sufficient?

@RvngSD Is it only my prejudice wondering if there can be something done to make the Romanian embassy employees more forthcoming?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I will call again and be more demanding, it is true that the Consulate employees arent that interested..

The Federal police (Bundespolizei) can issue an Emergency travel document (Notreiseausweis) to EU/EEA Citizens (and probably 3rd country nationals who are residents of other EU/EEA countries) under certain conditions:

Emergency travel document for persons without German citizenship
For citizens of the European Union, the European Economic Area or Switzerland, as well as for persons who are entitled to return to these countries, the Federal Police can issue an emergency travel document for a trip abroad or for re-entry. This only applies to avoid undue hardship or for reasons of particular public interest, if the issuance of a travel document by the country's own foreign representation or a foreign authority can no longer be expected in time.

An expired passport can be used:

Important information on issuing passport replacement documents
Identity and nationality must be proven by presenting official documents - generally an expired passport or passport replacement. A copy of this is not sufficient.

The application can be made online, so that the document can be prepaired beforehand and picked up at a pre-agreed place and time:

Electronic application
To speed up the process of obtaining the passport replacement document you need, you can use the online application to send your personal details and the relevant travel data electronically to the relevant border authority, who will contact you promptly. They will also inform you about the modalities for collection.


Sources:

Passrechtliche Hinweise - Notreiseausweis für Personen ohne deutsche Staatsangehörigkeit (in German)


What exactly in the question makes you think that OP is experiencing 'undue hardship' or is travelling 'for reasons of particular public interest' or that he can't obtain travel documents from his own authorities? Unless those conditions are met, German authorities will not issue emergency travel documents for foreign citizens. He already confirmed that the Romanian Consulate will issue him emergency travel documents to go to Romania to obtain a new id.
